# Generated URL with token - The security token did not match

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, security-token

I'm trying to make a link that acts as the "save 2 copy" button on the edit page.

On the main page for the item, I am creating the link according to this documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms

```
<a href="<?php 
echo JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_pakker&view=jj_pakke&task=jj_pakke.save2copy&id=1&'. JSession::getFormToken() .'=1' );
?>">
```

Which generates links like:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php/jj_pakke/1?task=jj_pakke.save2copy&55cdb8304fef2c8a80be2620d18ae367=1
```

The error I'm getting is:

> security token did not match

Comment: You didn't show us when/where/how you are checking the token.  Are you using the `get` parameter? `JSession::checkToken( 'get' ) or die( 'Invalid Token' );`

Comment: I didn´t do that part, but I will check up on this and see how it works. But I think save2copy is a part of the joomla API https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Toolbar.ToolbarHelper.html#method_save2copy

Comment: I can see that the error comes from this function https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JControllerForm/save

Comment: You where right @mickmackusa. As in the link above, the function did not use 'get'. I change my code to use a from with 'post'.... Will you make it as an answer?

Comment: It is marked as an answer on the question that yours duplicated. Doing anything with it here is redundant.

Comment: @Arlen My dupe closure was a response to JonasB's request for an answer.  JonasB merely wanted a means to resolve the page which is a good behavior.  I elected to close the question rather than answer. This is the action dictated by my Stack Exchange ethics and my personal principles to honour the posters that came before me and encourage people to research within JSE for answers (search for keywords and tags) before posting a question.  That said, a dupe closure is not a "smack down", it presents another way to collect researchers from search results and point them to working solutions.

Comment: Wasn't meant as a smackdown; just as a description of reality. My apologies to you both if my haste made it seem otherwise.